# path till WEB-INF inside web application

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I am parsing the HttpRequest inside a web application. My **servlet extends HttpServlet**

I need to find the path till WEB-INF inside a **WAR file** so that file present inside WEB-INF can be accessed.

I cannot use Realpath so there has to be some alternative.

tried using

```
ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
InputStream input = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF");
```

but everytime

```
Sysem.out.println(input) returns null
```

Please suggest.

Comment: WEB-INF is a directory. What do you expect the above code to do? Why don't you try to access a file, as your question asks?

Comment: I need to access the file inside the WEB-INF folder. SO I need path atleast till WEB-INF.. That is what I am trying to do. I tried with / also, but stream is always null

Comment: So, if you need to load the file foo.txt, don't you think the path should be /WEB-INF/foo.txt?

Comment: I don't need to load the file. I only need the path till the file. The file will be loaded by another engine. I need to provide the path to the file.

Comment: There is no file. It's a resource inside a war file. What you should pass to the engine is an InputStream. And what you should do is get the InputStream using `servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INFfile.txt")`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the root web directory of your application like this:

```
servletContext.getRealPath(File.separator));
```

So assuming your WEB-INF is in there, you could do this:

```
 servletContext.getRealPath(File.separator + "/WEB-INF/whatever.file"));
```

It returns a String path, so to actually get the file:

```
 new File(servletContext.getRealPath(File.separator + "/WEB-INF/whatever.file")));
```